# i want to design these 2 boxes using css[image]?

Tags: css, image, html

[image]

i want to create this effect using css, can you see the big box with the title and the blog post, and little box with the date on it and the number of comments on it. its been puzzling me, an example would be great thanks guys :))

Comment: why don't you just install firefox and look at the example's css? Or an least, provide us with a link so that we can do this.

Comment: The example is right there in front of you, go to the page click View> Source and you'll have all you need.

Comment: i know i have looked at the source, but the author uses images, i dnt like images when it comes to designing stuff like this. :))

Comment: Have you tried examining the CSS that the site you want to emulate uses to create this effect? If you're using Firefox, you could try the awesome [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension; Chrome has its Developer Tools that you can access by selecting "Inspect element" from the context menu.

Comment: @joni go to www.muna-abigail.com its my friends blog

Comment: @getaway thanks for the info. I thought it was your cat's blog first, but now I know it.

Comment: @joni, is that meant to be a joke lol

Comment: @getaway no. As a fact, my own cat often steals my laptop and writes on her blog when I'm sleeping. She even finds out my password every time >.< I can't prove it, but I always find hairs on the keyboard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML just create two separate divs, one for the details and the other for the content.

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post_details">
        <div class="post_date">
            <div class="post_day">26</div>
            <div class="post_month">NOV/10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="post_comments">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_text">
        <div class="post_title">PASSION SUCCESS AND MONEY</div>
        <div class="post_title">A lot of people...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the CSS you could float them both left or absolute position the details box off to the side.

```
.post         { clear:both; width:600px; }
.post_details { float:left; width:53px; height:93px; background:#fff; }
.post_date    { width:48px; background:#ddd; }
.post_month   { width:48px; background:#666; }
.post_text    { float:left; width:545px; background:#fff; }
```

Comment: While you're at it you could give it some HTML5 love.

Comment: cheers your a genious, i just love it when people understand my question cheers +upvote from me :))

Comment: No problem. For trouble-shooting CSS I always try to imagine boxes around the objects I want to position, then I created the box structure and put the content inside.

Answer (score 1):

don't quite understand what's so puzzleling but if it's how the divs are arranged there's 100 ways it could be done one way would be something like

http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/1650/exampleai.png

if it's about how to get rounded corners it would be like jakub mentioned 
here is a sample

http://www.jsfiddle.net/KKpPQ/3/

Comment: thanks, the image you have shown is a bit different, im talking about the two divs being aligned in the way the image is shown, if its not puzzling then why dnt you try it. :))

Comment: added what meo did so you have a better picture of how it could look
you can see it here http://www.jsfiddle.net/KKpPQ/2/

Answer (score 1):

its pretty easy with some css3:

http://jsfiddle.net/meo/J9SjQ/

Answer (score 0):

The main trick would be in using the CSS3 `border-radius` property. That makes the boxes round. You'll have to use vendor prefixes to get this working in current browsers:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

Comment: thanks for the info, i know how to make boxes radius round, im talking about the postioning of the small box with the big box on the right aligned like in the image, thanks for the help though 
:))

Comment: just `use position:absolute` and negative margins.

Comment: [The latest versions of Webkit no longer need the prefix](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27578), so you can drop the `-webkit-`, unless you want to support Safari 4.0 and below. Oh, and Opera doesn't need a prefix either, so the `-o-` can go too.